# Bash loses variable when running from cron MacosX

Tags: bash, macos, cron

I have a script that's running fine from the command line (Macosx Big Sur), but when running from cron or launchd I'm losing the $file variable.

Also the Downloads/*.sh file is created from a website when I click on a button. So I know when there is a file(s)

From command line

```
Starting updating EXIF data
Updating: /Users/patrick_m/Downloads/1707.sh
```

From cron/launchd

```
Starting updating EXIF data
    Updating:  /Users/patrick_m/Downloads/*.sh
    /bin/sh: /Users/patrick_m/Downloads/*.sh: No such file or directory
    rm: /Users/patrick_m/Downloads/*.sh: No such file or directory
```

Doing an ls after the run the cron

```
Patricks-Mini Applications % ls /Users/patrick_m/Downloads/*.sh
/Users/patrick_m/Downloads/81.sh
```

The script

```
    #!/bin/bash

PATH=$PATH:/bin:/Applications/:/usr/local/mysql/bin/


## Start script ##
echo "Starting updating EXIF data"
for file in /Users/patrick_m/Downloads/*.sh; do
    echo "Updating: " $file

    ## Execute the exif file ##
    /bin/sh ${file}
    ## Get status of the update ##
    status=$?
    ## take some decision ##
    if [ $status -eq 0 ]; then
        ## id van record
        ID=`echo $(basename "$file") | cut -d'.' -f1`
        ## sql string based on id from filename
        SQL="USE fam; UPDATE roll_film_images SET exif_embed='1' WHERE id_roll_film_images='$ID'"
        echo $SQL > /tmp/update.sql
        ## Excecute SQL update
        mysql -u root -p'root' -h 192.168.1.77 -D fam < /tmp/update.sql
    fi

    ## Remove the exif update file
    /bin/rm $file
done
```

Comment: that's because there is no file that matches the glob `/Users/patrick_m/Downloads/*.sh`, so the loop sticks to the literal "/Users/patrick_m/Downloads/*.sh".

Comment: Ok, but there are several .sh files in that directory, please keep in mind that I'm no programmer

Comment: If the computer says there are no files there, I'm going to trust the computer more than I trust you. If you are convinced that the files existed at the time the `cron` job ran, please [edit] to update the question with the proof.

Comment: This may be to TCC ("Transparency Consent and Control")](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332673/what-and-how-does-macos-mojave-implement-to-restrict-applications-access-to-pers) restricting access to "personal" areas, like your Desktop folder. See ["On Catalina, how can a cronjob get permission to touch files on a USB disk?"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/372768/on-catalina-how-can-a-cronjob-get-permission-to-touch-files-on-a-usb-disk)

Comment: @tripleee: added the output of ls.

Comment: That demonstrates that there is a file there now, but that's not what I asked. In fact it seems fairly likely that the job ran successfully, and you didn't get a warning, and then it ran again, and failed, because the previous run cleared out all the files and no new ones appeared.

Comment: @GordonDavisson, Yes your remark of the TCC has let me find the solution !!
I needed to add crontab & cron  to the Full Disk Access

Comment: @tripleee, the solution was provided by Gordon

Comment: Your question should remain strictly a question. I have rolled back your edit, but please be more than welcome to post that as an answer, and eventually mark it as accepted.